# How to Update bulk records in one table by finding the column's value existence in another table using Stored procedures?

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.6

I have two tables namely **'loan_details'** and **'loan_mapping'**.  I need to set the **mod_id of loan_mapping table by the value which is present in the loan_details table**. So, it's bulk update of records (20K records) of 'loan_mapping' table only if the loan_number column of 'loan_mapping' table records present in 'loan_detail' table records. (I mean if Look up is successful using loan_number)

The definition of two tables are as follows:

```sql
CREATE TABLE public.loan_details 
(
  loan_number   bigint NOT NULL,
  crp_lob       integer,
  mod_id        integer,
  CONSTRAINT loan_details_pkey PRIMARY KEY (loan_number)
);

CREATE TABLE public.loan_mapping 
(
  loan_number           bigint NOT NULL,
  spoc_id               integer NOT NULL,
  assigned_datetime     timestamp without time zone,
  loan_spoc_map_id      integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval ('lsa_loan_spoc_mapping_loan_spoc_map_id_seq'::regclass),
  line_of_business_id   integer,
  mod_id                integer,
  CONSTRAINT loan_spoc_mapping_pk PRIMARY KEY (loan_spoc_map_id),
  CONSTRAINT fk_loan_spoc_loan_number FOREIGN KEY (loan_number) 
    REFERENCES public.loan_details (loan_number)
);
```

So, I need exact Stored procedure to do the required updates as mentioned in my summarized problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: update loan_mapping map set mod_id = (select det.mod_id from 
loan_details det where det.loan_number = map.loan_number) ; I used this query to update in my local machine. Since the number of records in "PROD" are more than 20K , my senior told, Stored Proc would be better solution instead of Update scripts. hence I posted asking for Stored Proc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any reason for a stored procedure here:

```sql
update loan_mapping lm
  set mod_id = ld.mod_id
from loan_details ld  
where ld.loan_number = lm.loan_number;
```